# Raspberry Pi zero w program crash after using gpio

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

Solved:
The problem was not from the software but the hardware. It seems like the pi zero w does not have enought power for a micro-servo-motor. The problem disappeared when I connected the servo to an extern power source.

My raspberry pi zero w hangs up after calling time.sleep in the following script. I have to stop the programm and reconnect to ssh.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

servo = 18
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(servo, gpio.OUT)

p = gpio.PWM(servo, 50)
p.start(2.5)

print("7.5")
p.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
print("changed duty cycle to 7.5") # <-- this is the last thing printed
time.sleep(3)
print("12.5")
p.ChangeDutyCycle(12.5)
time.sleep(3)
print("ended")

p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

This stops working after `print("changed duty cycle to 7.5")`

I tried to replace the sleep function with

```
t = time.time()
while time.time()-t < 4:
    pass
```

which works from time to time but is not consistent. 
When I replace the time.sleep with some calculations that take some time my programm stops working while executing `p.stop()`. If I comment the last two lines out my programm executes "successfully" but I cant do anything from the command line afterwards without the pi crashing.

I tested time.sleep in an other script on the same pi and everything works fine. I therefore think the problem has something to do with the access to the GPIO pins.

I'm using Raspbian with python 3.7.3. and my servo-motor (DS-140BBMG) is connected to the GPIO-18 pin, +5V and GND.

Edit:

I found an other methode to freeze my py without using the time module. 
When I execute the following code the first time he executes successfully (180deg turn and back). However, when executing it the second time the code hangs up at about 90deg.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

servo = 18
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(servo, gpio.OUT)

p = gpio.PWM(servo, 50)
p.start(2.5)

for i in range(1000000):
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(2.5 + i*0.00001)
for i in range(1000000):
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(12.5 - i*0.00001)

p.stop()
gpio.cleanup()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's because you're using a Linux OS which does multiprocessing and CPU scheduling. From the python docs on `time.sleep`, it says: "the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.".  If I was you, I would try sleeping using the `subprocess` module and see if that has the same problem.  `import subprocess` and then sleep like this: `subprocess.run(["sleep", "3"])`

Comment: @PeacefulJames I replaced both sleep functions with your solution and run the programm 3 times. The programm froze two times while running the first time ` subprocess.run(["sleep", "3"]) ` and once while executing it the second time (after the 12.5).

Comment: @PeacefulJames The crash was due to a lack of power in the pi and not the software. However, I still learned about a potential problem thanks to your answer anyway. Thank you

Comment: I really didn't do anything. I was just offering a "shot in the dark". I'm glad you found a solution. Good luck.

Comment: i had this exact same problem and ended up just powering my motor driver with a different battery.  I had a big powerful battery with lots of protection circuitry to try and run everything off of this but the motors still crashed the pi when started.